# In which paper did J. F. Plante introduce the notion of Holonomy Invariant Transverse Measure?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, ergodic-theory, foliations, holonomy

In which paper did J. F. Plante introduce (for the first time) the notion of **Holonomy Invariant Transverse Measure**?

I do appreciate any help can be provided.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It might be good to add the reference where the attribution comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without attributing ownership to Plante (because it seems to me this requires a historical study ($\dagger$)), probably the paper is "Foliations with Measure Preserving Holonomy", published in 1975. It seems in the literature it is common to cite this paper as well as Ruelle & Sullivan's 1975 paper "Currents, Flows and Diffeomorphisms". Garnett's 1981 PhD thesis *Functions and measures harmonic along the leaves of a foliation and the ergodic theorem* (available at https://doi.org/10.1349/ddlp.1154) seems like a useful source in this context.

($\dagger$) E.g. Schwartzman and Sacksteder's papers are also mentioned at times.